# What is GitHub /.well-known/openid-configuration URL?

Tags: github, oauth, openid

I am trying to find it in the developer doc but no luck:
https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/

Does GitHub expose a discovery endpoint for openid?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Appears Github only supports OAuth and not OpenID Connect.

This implies that only OAuth Client's are delegated access to a resources which belong to another.