# Multiple authentication servers for my OAuth 2 resource server

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have implemented a simple resource server with Spring Boot and Spring Oauth2 with Google as authentication server:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: clientId
            client-secret: clientSecret
            scope: openid,profile,email
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://accounts.google.com
          jwk-set-uri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
```

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/hi")
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()
                .and()
                .and()
                .cors().and().csrf().disable();

    }

}
```

How do I add a few more authentication servers like Github, Facebook, or Twitter?

Right now I am able to generate id_token and access_token for Google authentication but I am not sure if Github or Facebook supports it. I couldn't find anything similar in their documentation.

In the end, I want to have 3 authentication providers to which I will be able to generate id_token and send it as an Authentication header in Postman. I am not even able to find **jwk-set-uri** or **issuer-uri** for Github, to replace the Google authentication server with Github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multi tenant scenarios (several token issuers), you should have a look at https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons. Your use-case is very close to https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_oauthentication.

Spring boot team decided not to support multiple token issuers: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/30108#issuecomment-1163292478

Regarding Github and OpenID: [What is GitHub /.well-known/openid-configuration URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52157568/what-is-github-well-known-openid-configuration-url). You can still use it as OAuth2 provider, following [Github doc](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/), but what Github produces as access-token is an opaque token (not a JWT). To check that the token is valid (issued by github, has not expired, wasn't revoqued, ...) and get info about authenticated user, you have to issue a request to Github API, which is pretty limitative. You could use an OpenID authorization-server (like Keycloak) as [identity broker](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_single_sign-on/7.0/html/server_administration_guide/identity_broker), which would

- use Github (and others) as identity provider
- provide your clients with JWT access-tokens (Postman, web apps, native mobile apps, etc.)
- maybe centralise user roles management

Comment: thank you for the answer. I believe I am missing some knowledge about OpenID and Oauth2, but how, for example, front-end or postman, should use Github as OAuth2 provider? They don't provide token like google and have to be redirected to spring URI 
( /login/oauth2/code/github ) in order to validate the code that the authorization server provided. How can I send requests to my app from postman or make it redirect to localhost:3000/home, after successful authorization?

Comment: @eternal I haden't checked if Github was providing with JWTs as access-token before answering. They don't, which would make flow pretty complicated to use this opaque token to authorize the request to your resource-server. Easiest way to solve this is using an OIDC authorization server as identity broker (something like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cffN1ApR6o0)